# Multi-user calendar program my wife and I can share?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, hotmail

I'm not sure if anything exists, but I'm trying to figure out a way for my wife and I (or more) to utilize a web-based calendar system.

We both use Windows Live Mail, so my first guess is that we use that. However, my guess is that if I set up her account to use my login, she'll get all my contacts as well. I don't know if windows live calendar supports multiple shared logins.

Maybe there are some options with google calendar? However, I'm finding it hard to 2-way-sync google calendar with windows live mail.

I also host my own web server, so if there's anything that I can download and run myself, that's an option as well. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to jump into Google with both feet, Google Calendar will let you do this. It's been a godsend for my wife and I.

We both share (read-only) access to our personal calendars. We also have shared admin rights to a calendar for each of our children, the house, and local events (that we might wish to attend).

We both also use Android devices, which syncs up seamlessly. So we now both know what the other has going on and where the kids need to be, when the HVAC filter needs to be changed, and whether we can fit the music festival next weekend into our schedule.

How you get that to work well with Windows Live Mail I don't know. The wife and I drank the Google Kool-Aid a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

At work we use outlook for the same purpose. Somebody puts an event, and if you accept it, it shows on your calendar. Not sure if that works for you.

Comment: That's using exchange server. I'm looking for a solution more for home use.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Google Calendar for whatever reason, you could roll your own with [Kronolith](http://www.horde.org/apps/kronolith).

Answer (score 0):

If you want two people share one copy of file, you can have a try of Efficient calendar Network. Both of you can manage and update this file together, and you can see the latest information easily. You can visit here to know more: http://www.efficientsoftware.net/business-calendar/